# Can I travel to London (UK) on a valid French Titre de Sejour (passeport talent-chercheur)?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, london, conferences

I am doing my PhD in France. It is required that I must go to London to attend some conference (2 days). My nationality is Indian and currently I have this **Visa Long Séjour Valant Titre de Séjour mention “passeport talent-chercheur"**. Can I travel to London with this or I shall have to do the visa formality to go to london and then buy the tickets?

Comment: That’s a residence permit for France, I believe. In which case it doesn’t allow you to enter the UK, you will need a visa. You can check here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Answer (score 3):

According to the [UK visa check tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/work/six_months_or_less) if you:

- are an Indian citizen
- are coming to the UK for an academic visit
- are staying for less than six months

You need to apply for a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa). Having a French residency permit does not seem to matter at all in this case.

Quoting from the linked website:

> ## You'll need a visa to work, do business or academic research in the UK
>
> The visa you need to apply for depends on your circumstances.
>
> ### Business visits
>
> You can apply:
>
> - for a [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) - eg if you’re coming to the UK for conferences, meetings, training, academic research or a sabbatical
> - as a visitor doing a ‘[permitted paid engagement](https://www.gov.uk/permitted-paid-engagement-visa)’ (you must have been invited to the UK because of your expertise) - you can only stay for up to 1 month